# My android app is detecting the same bluetooth device multiple times

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm using code from the Android developer website to detect Bluetooth devices in range, and adding them to an ArrayAdapter. Problem is, each device gets added to the ArrayAdapter 5-6 times. Right now, I'm just using the code from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices

Here's what I have:

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();      
mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
```

Any idea what's causing this? And what can I do to get a device to be added only once to the ArrayAdapter, instead of 5 times?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if its a bug or what but I've also experienced this on some of my devices. To solve this, add found devices in a `List` only once with some checks. See below:

```
private List<BluetoothDevice> tmpBtChecker = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery starts    
            if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                //clearing any existing list data
                tmpBtChecker.clear();
            }

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = 
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // Add the name and address to an array adapter
                if(!tmpBtChecker.contains(device)){
                   tmpBtChecker.add(device);
                   mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I actually had this before. But I was told this wasn't exactly an "elegant" solution. Do you think it might just be a device specific bug? I wish I had another device to test it on...

Comment: I usually had this problem on samsung devices. I think it is an elegant solution, otherwise how do you plan to solve this?

Comment: I was going to suggest checking if it's already in the list but this seems better.

Comment: You can make this more efficient by using a HashSet. List.Contains is big O notation (O)n, whereas HashSet is (O)1. I.e HashSet is more efficient as does not need you to iterate over the entire list.  `private Set<BluetoothDevice> foundDevices = new HashSet<>();` .... `if(foundDevices.contains(device)){
                    return;
                }
                foundDevices.add(device);`

Comment: This doesn't solve the bug. Its just a work-around. This answer doesn't help.